# Die($array['key']) Results in "e", rather than the array value

Tags: php

I try to run a php-script with:

```
die($postdata['entry.852552993']);
```

$postadata has a key called entry.852552993. When I run the script I get

```
e
```

As a response.

Print_r renders

```
entry.852552993=asdf&entry.369545365=asdf&entry.294310521=kristoffer%40nolgren.se&entry.1273939785=&entry.1493395350=&entry.120344222=&entry.333376545=&entry.79269841=Attending
```

The response I would like is `adsf`

Comment: and what do you expect? what is array value for that key?

Comment: And the var_dump on `$postdata`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$postdata is a string. You need to convert it into an array to be able to index it like you are.

Try this:

```
$postdata = "entry.852552993=asdf&entry.369545365=asdf&entry.294310521=kristoffer%40nolgren.se&entry.1273939785=&entry.1493395350=&entry.120344222=&entry.333376545=&entry.79269841=Attending";

parse_str($postdata, $output);
//print_r($output);
echo $output['entry_852552993'];
```

I've found that parse_str converts the dots in your variable names into underscores, so `entry.85xxxxx` becomes `$output['entry_85xxxxx']`